# Different between normal function and arrow function: arguments not defined return an error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arguments

ES6 NEWBY

I'm new to es6 and I have a problem with the arrow function that I wasn't able to resolve or find anywhere.

Here's my problem, let's take this function as a reference:

Javascript:

```
const plus = function() {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = arguments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum += arguments[i];
        console.log(i);
    }
    return sum;
    console.log(arguments);
}

console.log(plus(2,4,6,8));
```

It works fine, the result is gonna be 20, and the browser is able to interpret it. The only problem is that when I try to translate in es6, the function will return an error, in this case, arguments is not defined:

```
const plus = () => {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = arguments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum += arguments[i];
        console.log(i);
    }
    return sum;
    console.log(arguments);
}

console.log(plus(2,4,6,8));
```

I get that part, but even if I define arguments as an empty array, the result will be still the same.

I'm trying to understand the error, but not like how to solve it, the theory behind to better use es6.

Thanks

Comment: An arrow function doesn't get an `arguments` object. You can use explicit spread syntax to capture the actual arguments in an array.

Comment: Also [the MDN documentation explains this and other important differences.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Spread_syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) :

```js
const plus = (...arguments) => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = arguments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    sum += arguments[i];
    // console.log(i);
  }
  // console.log(arguments);
  return sum;
}

console.log(plus(2, 4, 6, 8));
```

Comment: Do I need to explicit the parameter? Or is there another way to avoid that. The spread syntax is the way to go

Comment: yes you do need  to explicit the parameter

Comment: const plus = (...arguments).

In this case, I'm using arguments (it is a little bit confusing the name that I chose) as a parameter. Do I really need to use a parameter?

Comment: Ok, I got it and the concept of the rest parameter, thanks

Comment: Using `arguments` as the example name seems like a bad idea. It's also not valid in strict-mode code. Probably worth changing to `args`?